# On the intellectual property of animals, a story of monkeys and cats!

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, intellectual-property

The story of the [monkey who took a selfie](http://www.insurancejournal.com/news/national/2015/09/25/382768.htm) is, by now, probably widely known. Summary: a court said that the owner of the camera is not entitled to rights because the picture was taken by the monkey, not the human.

My question is the following: I saw a [video of a cat playing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0zgQAp7EYw)  the piano. 
(Hear me out...)

(Her name is Nora).
Now, I understand the *video* is the property of its author: a human being.

But what about the **"music"**. Just the notes. 
I also understand that if the "music" was taught by a human being (like what happens sometimes in a circus) the music is the human's, but in this case, when (it seems) the "music" is really "played" by the cat (rather randomly), is it copytight-able ? I understand the anumal cannot actually have the property, but can his owner?

EDIT: I fogot to state one way this question can be tricky: 
One difference is that the photographer didn't **own** the monkey, but the cat is definitely **owned**.

(The [countries](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/aug/22/monkey-business-macaque-selfie-cant-be-copyrighted-say-us-and-uk) are UK and US)

Comment: Which country does this happen in? This is likely a novel area of law but I would expect it to follow the precedent set by the selfie case.

Comment: @jimsug, thanks, I edited to put the link for the countries. It seems to be based on older laws, the main debate seems to be on whether the human had any *creative added value* to the picture...And I want to say "duh", but I am not an expert...Hence the question.

Comment: The article about the photograph appears to have been written before the case was decided.  Do you have a link to anything covering the court's decision?

Comment: [PDF](http://copyright.gov/comp3/chap300/ch300-copyrightable-authorship.pdf) and [weblink](http://www.csmonitor.com/Innovation/Tech-Culture/2014/0822/US-government-Monkey-selfies-ineligible-for-copyright) explicitly mentioning this incident.

Answer (score 3):

[17 USC §102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/102):

> Copyright protection subsists, in accordance with this title, in original works of authorship

[17 USC §201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/201):

> Copyright in a work protected under this title vests initially in the author or authors of the work.

[Animals cannot be authors](http://www.courthousenews.com/2016/01/29/monkey%20selfie.pdf). To the extent that the cat's owner could be an author, copyright only subsists in "original works of authorship". The test for originality in the US was laid out in *[Feist Pubs., Inc. v. Rural Tel. Svc. Co., Inc.](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/499/340/)*, 499 U.S. 340 (1991):

> The constitutional requirement necessitates independent creation plus a modicum of creativity.

The music produced by the cat was not a product of even a modicum of creativity on the part of the cat's owner (or anyone, for that matter). No copyright subsists in the notes randomly chosen by the cat.

Comment: Yet composers apparently retain copyright in music created through random processes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleatoric_music. How is the participation of a cat any different from the casting of dice? If you ask me, the monkey selfie guy hired the wrong lawyer.